# Using xsd.exe to generate C# classes, how to specify an existing type?

Tags: c#, xsd

I have an XML Schema file (XSD) which I'm using to generate C# classes using the [xsd tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) supplied with Visual Studio.

If it's possible, how do I specify an existing type as the type of an element? Say I want to do this

```xml
<xs:element name="Table">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <!-- ...snip... -->
            <xs:element name="CellValues" type="ADODB.RecordSet"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

How do I tell xsd that `ADODB.RecordSet` is an existing type in an imported assembly?

Comment: Is the ADODB.RecordSet available in other xsd ?

Comment: I suppose xsd.exe could generate the schema for that type...

Comment: What does CellValues show up as when you create your class? Object?

Comment: @JMK it fails, saying that the type is not defined. I could get xsd.exe to generate the schema for that type but that seems the wrong way to go about it...

Comment: Maybe use the `/namespace:` parameter to add the namespace that `ADODB.RecordSet` resides in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I managed to do something by implementing [`SchemaImporterExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.advanced.schemaimporterextension%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```cs
namespace SchemaImport
{
    public class ADODBSchemaImporterExtension : SchemaImporterExtension
    {

        public override CodeExpression ImportDefaultValue(string value, string type)
        {
            return new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(type);
        }

        public override string ImportSchemaType(XmlSchemaType type,
            XmlSchemaObject context, XmlSchemas schemas, XmlSchemaImporter importer,
            CodeCompileUnit compileUnit, CodeNamespace codeNamespace,
            CodeGenerationOptions options, CodeDomProvider codeGenerator)
        {
        return null;
        }

        public override string ImportSchemaType(string name, 
            string ns, XmlSchemaObject context, XmlSchemas schemas, XmlSchemaImporter importer, 
            CodeCompileUnit compileUnit, CodeNamespace mainNamespace, 
            CodeGenerationOptions options, CodeDomProvider codeProvider)
        {
            if (name.StartsWith("ADODB."))
            {
                compileUnit.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("adodb.dll");
                mainNamespace.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("ADODB"));
                return name.Substring(name.IndexOf(".") + 1);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

together with defining the `ADODB.Recordset` as an `xsd:complexType`:

```xml
<xs:element name="Table">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <!-- ...snip... -->
            <xs:element name="CellValues" type="ADODB.RecordSet"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="ADODB.Recordset"/>
```

I then had to add this class to `machine.config`:

```xml
<system.xml.serialization>
    <schemaImporterExtensions> 
        <add type="SchemaImport.ADODBSchemaImporterExtension, SchemaImport, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd583032ee337c41" /> 
    </schemaImporterExtensions>
</system.xml.serialization>
```

and specify the assembly in a parameter file (the `/p:parameters.xml` switch) to xsd.exe:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd xmlns='http://microsoft.com/dotnet/tools/xsd/'>
    <generateClasses language='c#' namespace='TableDocument'>
        <schemaImporterExtensions>
            <type>SchemaImport.ADODBSchemaImporterExtension, SchemaImport, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd583032ee337c41</type>
        </schemaImporterExtensions>
    </generateClasses>
</xsd>
```

I ended up with a .cs file with the appropriate Table class, in the TableDocument namespace that had the ADODB as a reference and `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would help?

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.71).aspx )

```
/t[ype]:typename
```

> Specifies the name of the type to create a schema for. You can specify
>   multiple type arguments. If typename does not specify a namespace,
>   Xsd.exe matches all types in the assembly with the specified type. If
>   typename specifies a namespace, only that type is matched. If typename
>   ends with an asterisk character (*), the tool matches all types that
>   start with the string preceding the *. If you omit the /type option,
>   Xsd.exe generates schemas for all types in the assembly.

Comment: I think this is the inverse of what is asked in the question:
the question asked for the possibility to generate a class from a schema.
As far as I understand from the documentation you provided this option is used to generate a schema from the classes.

Comment: it might be, its early Monday and coffee hasn't kicked in fully :) at any rate, if its not on the MSDN documentation and using the  /t:ADODB.RecordSet with /c does not work for the posters needs, then as far as I know it can't be done.

Comment: thanks for your reply, @RobertH but this is how to generate the xml from an existing assembly. I was thinking of going down this route and including that xsd so the type is generated with the main xsd file, but I [found another way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11615813/69820).