# Using xsd.exe to generate C# classes with SchemaImporterExtension. Without modifying machine.config

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I have two different xsd files associated to two different VS2010 projects.

The first one, named `BasicTypes.xsd` is "built" first using `xsd.exe` and generated classes are built in my `NetToolbox.dll` assembly.

When building the second one (named `Entity.xsd`), I need to reuse already generated class (Available in `NetToolbox.dll`) because types in `Entity.xsd` are defined in `BasicTypes.xsd`.  This is in assembly `EntityProvider.dll`.

Moreover, at runtime, I must pass these objects from `EntityProvider.dll` to `NetToolbox.dll` so having the same class definition is mandatory (I think, maybe I am wrong here).

This question is very similar to the following link but the proposed answer is not possible for me (Altering `machine.config`) : [Using xsd.exe to generate C# classes, how to specify an existing type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11610186/2033098)

I tried the proposed solution (By modifying `machine.config`) without success I really had a hard time correctly specifying the assembly in both machine.config and xsd.exe parameter.xml file.

```
<system.xml.serialization>
    <schemaImporterExtensions> 
        <add type="SchemaImport.ADODBSchemaImporterExtension, SchemaImport, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd583032ee337c41" /> 
    </schemaImporterExtensions>
</system.xml.serialization>
```

For example, here are the two XSDs.
BasicTypes.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             targetNamespace="http://www.tempuri.com/BasicTypes"
             xmlns="http://www.tempuri.com/BasicTypes"
             elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:complexType name="PositionType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="latitude" type="xs:double" />
            <xs:element name="longitude" type="xs:double" />
            <xs:element name="altitude" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and Entity.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             targetNamespace="http://www.tempuri.com/Entity"
             xmlns="http://www.tempuri.com/Entity"
             elementFormDefault="qualified"
             xmlns:bt="http://www.tempuri.com/BasicTypes">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.tempuri.com/BasicTypes" schemaLocation="directory\BasicTypes.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="entity" type="EntityType" />

    <xs:complexType name="EntityType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="bt:PositionType">
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Using any other third party tool than the one provided by the .NET framework (I'm at 4.0) or VS2010 is not an option (Security restrictions)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can register the schema importer extension in a configuration file for the `xsd.exe` utility itself instead of in the `machine.config` file.

To do this, make a copy of the `xsd.exe` application somewhere in your project's directory structure and create a file named `xsd.exe.Config` in the same directory. Add the lines to register the schema importer extension inside a `configuration` root element.

For your example, the `xsd.exe.Config` file would look like the following. Note that a `name` attribute is required in the `add` element, I've used the name of the extension class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.xml.serialization>
        <schemaImporterExtensions> 
            <add name="ADODBSchemaImporterExtension" type="SchemaImport.ADODBSchemaImporterExtension, SchemaImport, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd583032ee337c41" /> 
        </schemaImporterExtensions>
    </system.xml.serialization>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This probably means that I have to register my generated assembly in GAC ?  (The base XSD is part of a custom .NET assembly)  Or is there a way to force the assembly path ?